# Proof of area formula from stokes theorem

Tags: calculus, vectors, stokes-theorem

Prove that the area enclosed by a curve $C$ in a plane having normal $a\hat i+b\hat j+c\hat k$ is given by [image]

Stokes theorem:

$$\int\int (\nabla\times F)\cdot n\text{d}A=\oint_CF.\text{d}r$$

I took $$F=\frac{z}{b}\hat i+\frac{x}{c}\hat j+\frac{y}{a}\hat k$$
So that the LHS becomes $3A$. But the RHS does not match with the one given on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for $\vec F=\hat x(bz-cy)+\hat y (cx-az)+\hat z(ay-bx)$, we have

$$\oint_C \vec F(x,y,z)\cdot d\vec \ell=\int_C ((bz-cx)\,dx+(cx-az)\,dy+(at-bx)\,dz) \tag 1$$

Furthermore, note that $\nabla \times \vec F(x,y,z)=2\left(\hat x a+\hat yb+\hat zc\right)$ so that

$$\begin{align}
\int_S \nabla \times \vec F(x,y,z) \cdot \hat n\,dS&=2\int_S \left(\hat x a+\hat yb+\hat zc\right)\cdot \frac{\left(\hat x a+\hat yb+\hat zc\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\,dS\\\\
&=2\int_S (1)\,dS\\\\
&=2\times\text{The area of}\,\,S \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Therefore, from Stokes's Theorem, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal and we can assert that

$$\frac12 \oint_C \vec F(x,y,z)\cdot d\vec \ell=\text{The area of}\,\,S$$